# JQuery move to next element not working

Tags: jquery

i've been working with these for couple days , cant figure out how to make it happen... pls advice

http://jsfiddle.net/kbspot/fjVhY/

all thumbs displayed in Bottom, when a user clicked on thumb a large preview will show ... i got it working

Problem:
Another thing i would like to add is when a user clicked on the large preview, NEXT thumb (bottom panel) will be selected. but it's not working as i wanted, the Next thumb is not selected.

```
//Click on thumbnail (this is working perfectly)
$(".panel-bottom li").click(function () {
    var $activetab = $('li.active');        
    //$activetab.('IMG').hide();
    $activetab.removeClass('active');       
    $(this).addClass('active');

    //$(this).next().css({'border': '2px solid red'});
});

//Large Preview  click (this is the problem)
$("li.active .container").click(function () {
    //alert($(this).parent().html());
    var $activetab = $(this);       
    var $nexttab = $activetab.next();   

    $(this).removeClass();      
    $nexttab.addClass("active");
});
```

sorry, im not sure how to explain it but im sure you get it, hopefully

Comment: MildlyInteresting & Phil Cook, thank you ... after checking your codes i found the problem . Sorry for the fiddle.    [code]  // Large Preview click  
    $(".container").click(function () {  
    var $activetab = $(this).parent();   
    var $nexttab = $activetab.next();  
    $activetab.removeClass("active");
    $nexttab.addClass("active");
    return false; // this will prevent it from going back to previous     element

    });[code]

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle isnt properly showing up for me, but from the code here it looks like in the large preview click, `$activetab` should not be the `li.active .container` element, but its parent `li.active`, as in the first part?

```
//Large Preview  click (this is the problem)
$("li.active .container").click(function () {
    //alert($(this).parent().html());
    var $activetab = $(this).parent(); // Updated this line    
    var $nexttab = $activetab.next();   

    $(this).removeClass();      
    $nexttab.addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your js fiddle is a little broken as it looks like the images are pointing to your local development.

```
<img src="http://lensamaya/basic/photo/images/1.jpg" alt="From off a hill whose concave womb reworded" />
```

However I think I can see your problem in that you are dropping down into the container div and trying to goto the next element. However you need to go up a level first to your li element and then drop down again.

Something like this would work.

```
$("li.active .container").click(function () {
    //alert($(this).parent().html());
    var $activetab = $(this);       
    var $nexttab = $activetab.parent().next().children('.container');

    $(this).removeClass();      
    $nexttab.addClass("active");
});
```